# What could a Medieval society do with excess animal blood?

Tags: medieval, religion, blood

In my fantasy project I have a vaguely medieval society (specifically the high period). However some of  their religious practices are more along the lines of a iron age society. One of the biggest ones is they still practice animal sacrifice (I know some cultures did around the time, but I couldn't find many European ones, save things like bull fights)

In their religious beliefs Omnis, the flayed God, demands the use of sacrifices to appease for one's sins, but also to "balance" the world. Omnis flayed himself to make the world so in their theology everyone owes a debt to Omnis. This debt also manifests into "balancing" between the two worlds: the Waking and Dreaming world which becomes unbalanced with human actions ex: hunting. the payment of this debt is usually young and ample farm animals such as: goats, sheeps, cows. Usually a young healthy animal with the best sacrifices being virgin animals.

In the ritual the animals throat is slit in a very specific spot and the blood is drained out of the animal. The blood is not allowed to touch and thus defile the (usually temple) ground so it is collected in large jars. However after the sacrifice the blood can be used for whatever purpose.

What uses could a medieval society have for these large quantities of blood? I'm looking mainly for domestic and commercial uses since there is going to be a lot of excess blood.

Note: contact with blood is considered impure, but you'd just have to be ritually "cleaned" after using it. In universe people joke how butchers are holier then the priests since they have to purify themselves virtually every day.

Comment: It would be instructive to understand what you consider to be *"large quantities"* of blood. As far as I can tell, since the source of the blood is slaughtered animals, the amount of available blood is not very large at all, and definitely not larger that what would be usually available in any human society. See [blood sausages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_sausage), [black pudding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_pudding), and [blood as food](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_as_food) in general. The question is not well thought.

Comment: If you are "sacrificing" something to the gods - it would not typically then be available for people to use (most was just burned or poured over ground or etc). Have you research the modern animal sacrifices that still occur and seen what is done with remains or blood in these? (yes, they still exist see Eid al-Adha or Gadhimai)

Comment: @JGreenwell: In the Antiquity, animals who were sacrificed to the gods (including those sacrificed to the One True Living God of the Hebrews) were not completely destroyed in the process; most of the carcass was consumed by mortal humans.

Comment: This sounds like it belongs on the history stack

Comment: @AlexP the flesh not the blood in most of those cases (Roman, Jewish, or other)

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:religion]?  Should the answers only be from the perspective of religious uses?  Keep in mind the tag reflects the question, not the backstory.  If religion is simply the backstory that justifies the existence of the blood, you should remove the tag.  If you keep the tag, then all answers should be judged and voted upon based on whether or not they describe *religious* uses.

Comment: Also, I agree with @AlexP when he asks just how much blood we're talking about.  The ancient Jews sacrificed *a lot.*  So much so that the temple during the Roman era was designed to be flooded to wash the blood out into a nearby valley.  Blood is under pressure, so it's basically impossible to keep all of it off the ground (and your clothes...).  The jars are impractical for any volume not measured in tens or *maybe* hundreds of gallons a day.  Such small amounts can simply be disposed of.  Would a reservoir w/trough make more sense?  The engineer in me is complaining.

Comment: @JBH at max you'd have a hundred oxen sacrificed  (during the soltices) in a day at one location. Throughout the years you'd have periodic sacrifices on holy days and feast days (roughly twice a month) and then sporadic sacrifices by the faithful throughout the week. For simplicity let's say something comparable to Jews during the reign of Herod. Now for the blood: of course some will get on the floor you're not supposed to let it gush all over the temple grounds. I based that kinda off of the idea that catholic priests weren't supposed to draw blood, but in this case the temple floor.

Comment: People are clever.  Unless mandated by their god to use jars or urns, they'll create a sacrificial table with channels to drain the blood away to someplace more convenient.  (What the Jews did at the time of Herod would be very impractical via jars.) Just a thought as you're designing your religion (woo-hoo!  [Cultural worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7356/40609)!).

Comment: @JBH don't worry I've got plenty of culture questions, :P

Comment: Make blood sausage. An acquired taste, to be sure, but one I expect is well worth the effort. :-}

Comment: It's completely normal to turn blood in to sausage, it's a very common in many countries.

Comment: @JGreenwell That's true. Hebrew sacrifices included sprinkling the altar with the blood and the people. Not sure what they did with the rest. The priests also had limited access to the meat. Most was destroyed. Roman Jupiter sacrifices did something similar with the blood, and otherwise burned it, I think. The meat was a shared meal as part of the ceremony, but the fat and skin was burned together.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Growing the sacred crops.

[Blood is an excellent fertilizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_meal).

You talk about the blood not being able to touch the ground, but then you ask for domestic or commercial uses for it.  So either enough time has passed with it being in a jug, or it's transformed in some other way (like holy water is), or it's used for a special purpose.  Even though you state that the blood can later "be used for any purpose" you might still want some mystery and awe around it.

In many cultures, the core crop (like corn in the pre-colonization Americas) is considered sacred.  So pour the blood on the fields.  Time it ritually so it coincides with the best time to add high-nitrogen fertilizer.

If there's more blood than needed, pour some of it on adjacent ground and then allow farmers to move the "blessed" soil to spread on other fields, or in kitchen gardens.  The town might even sell some blessed soil to outsiders, if there is enough.

Depending on the agricultural need and the amounts of blood, this can be an annual, quarterly, or monthly ritual.

Comment: Monthly ritual... Blood... Makes me think of holy rituals fertilizing the fields with menstrual blood.

Comment: @arp I could totally see a spiritual connection between the two...

Comment: @arp I think the egyptians did that.

Comment: This video from the best series ever comes to mind: https://youtu.be/jBEcJBuveTA

Comment: FYI, only said the blood cannot touch temple ground (which makes sense)

Answer (score 46):

Eat it: Turn it into [black pudding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_pudding). Or drink it, perhaps [mixed with milk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maasai_people#Diet).

BTW, the [druidic religion sacrificed animals](https://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/celt/rac/rac19.htm), [as well as probably humans](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2009/03/druids-sacrifice-cannibalism/). In the absence of Christians and Romans it's not too much of a stretch to imagine that surviving until medieval times.

Comment: The Romans had animal sacrifice so only half that (and it still existed/exists in certain sects of [Christianity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_sacrifice#Christianity) though certainly not followed by the majority of the branches). Also, we only have the Roman sources on Druidic human sacrifice and they are highly suspect.

Comment: I wonder if the Americans are the only meat eaters who do not eat blood sausages.  How did that happen?

Comment: @JGreenwell: The Romans even practiced *human* sacrifice occasionally. It was indeed rare but definitely not unheard of. As for the Greeks, see Iphigenia.

Comment: @AlexP i.e. if one has evidence it would be good to add it to the answer (interesting research is always worth a + with me)

Comment: @JGreenwell: It's not some nifty research, it's well-known that the Romans occasionally practiced human sacrifice as a sort of last-ditch resort to gain the favor of the gods. See for example the short FAQ titled "[Human sacrifice in Ancient Rome](http://societasviaromana.net/Collegium_Religionis/human_sacrifice.php)" by M. Horatius Piscinus (a pseudonym, obviously) at [SocietasViaRomana.net](http://societasviaromana.net/).

Comment: @AlexP not from you (there are some very interesting pieces on how long that practice lasted in Rome but, yes, it is fairly established with Ancient Rome) but from K. Morgan in the answer. If one is answering this, or any Q, with a historically based answer (or assertion), one (meaning anyone) should also cite references or some sort of research to improve the answer. Also, the answer cites the Druids which I find interesting given how little we actually know about Druidic society/culture

Comment: @JGreenwell I'm currently on mobile so citations are hard, but I will add some when I get a chance.

Comment: @JGreenwell  Some of the druidic artifacts that they used to collect blood from human sacrifices (blades and bowls) had human blood residue when tested. (Think that article was in natl geo. around '90ish, but I haven't been thinking about it in decades.)

Comment: @JGreenwell Also the Roman Triumph celebrations usually ended with the murder of some enemy POWs, which an special interest in enemy leaders and kings, e.g. [Vercingetorix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vercingetorix#Battle_of_Alesia,_imprisonment,_and_death).

Comment: @Willk You ain't been to Louisiana then. Order you some [boudin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boudin) (pronounced boo-dan, for local flavor).

Comment: The last recorded Roman human sacrifice (triumphs weren't considered sacrifices but executions) was after Hannibal's victory at Cannae. Faced with the loss of two consular armies and most of the Senate, they consulted the Sybiline Book and came up with the idea of sacrificing a Greek and a slave to get back in the gods' favors.

Comment: The average eater in the US rejects a huge number of meat products that are commonly eaten in most other parts of the world. Most organ meats are shunned, tongue, tripe, blood products, and animal meats outside the most basic (cow, pig, chicken, turkey) are rare to see outside of specialty stores, high end restaurants and certain cultural restaurants (like you may find tripe at a dim sum or hot pot place).  I have no idea why we're so particular... I think the ability to be picky/wasteful leads to the gradual narrowing of tastes, but that's just a theory.

Answer (score 14):

Blood is a building material.

- mixed with clay/lime it can be used as paint, or plaster on walls. This gives the wall a lot more resistance to water.
- Mixed with clay is used for capping chimneys.  The blood prevents erosion of the cap by rain.
- Can also be used to grout flagstones.
- Mixed with water, and eggs can be used as a deer repellant to keep the kings deer from eating your fruit trees.
- Can be made into blood pudding, blood sausage.
- Can be used as an ingredient in feeding the Lord's Hounds.

And most of it was used this way.  While sacrificial animals weren't common in Medieval Europe, animal slaughter was common, and not much of the animal was thrown away.

---

Darker uses:  Some magic systems are powered by blood.  Steal the sacrificial blood for your practice of the Dark Arts.

Comment: There are areas of England where the houses were traditionally painted pink. Originally, this would have been exactly the blood/whitewash paint that you mention.

Answer (score 11):

Blood is high in protein. They can use blood to supplement dishes or as a source of cheap protein for poor people (and animals).

Back in my homeland (Portugal) and in other countries, people eat blood to enrich dishes, and it was used in the past as a poor's substitute for meat:

- it is added to rice and a kind of thick soup;
- they curl it with vinegar and fry it, and it almost looks like meat, only so softer;
- also blood sausages;
- using it on top of game/chicken as a sauce or as a broth for cooking the meat;
- sweets based on it - there are a couple of desserts based on blood, never tried them;

There are also other cultures which drink it as a tonic. Maybe turning drinking blessed blood into a religious ritual.

Answer (score 1):

K. Morgan's answer is on right track, but fails to show just how common use of blood in culinary arts is.

**[Blood sausage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_sausage) in different countries is known as: kaszanka, blutwurst, krvavica, krovianka, blodpølse, vėdarai, asins desa, boudin noir, morcilla, sanguinaccio, blóðmör, sargyangma, 'dồi tiết', ไส้กรอกเลือด, longganisang dugo, saren, sundae, 豬血糕, morcilla, prieta, chouriço, mutura.**

Blood sausage in most general form combines ground offal, ground fat, blood and cereal like rice or psedocereal like buckwheat as plant additions and is traditional in many cuisines in entire world.

I doubt if traditional cuisine (as in not created as a mash-up of existing cuisines in modern times) lacking blood sausage even exists.

Blood pudding is just UK's variant.

**Animal products were historically a luxury not everyone can afford**, thus it was important to let nothing go to waste to make use of that precious protein, iron and other elements.

Wiki on "[offal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offal)":

> In some parts of Europe, scrotum, brain, chitterlings (pig's small intestine), trotters (feet), heart, head (of pigs, calves, sheep and lamb), kidney, liver, spleen, "lights" (lung), sweetbreads (thymus or pancreas), fries (testicles), tongue, snout (nose), tripe (reticulum) and maws (stomach) from various mammals are common menu items.

Parts about other continents don't have such a nice soudbite list, but make no mistake, they have same traditions about using everything.

As such, it would be incredible waste to let post-sacrifice blood go bad if you can turn it into food instead. **Since you have decreed blood impure in your religion, consider people of your world purifying blood sausage in smoke. That would be called [smoking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoking_(cooking)), an excellent way of improving taste and shelf life of animal products.** Has a benefits of being actual culinary technique and being just roundabout enough to fit crazy religious ways of thinking.

Comment: Everything but the squeal.

Answer (score 0):

When Omnis flayed himself to create the world, this his skin become the world? And did his blood become the lakes and rivers? Then so should the remaining blood of the sacrifices. Always poor it into the same spot, until a lake of blood builds a symbol of the great work Omnis did. Or pour it into the river, to become one with his blood.

Comment: *until a lake of blood builds*. Sorry but it won't happen. You need prodigious amounts of blood (and slaughtered animals, which are expensive in a medieval setting) to have anything more than "a puddle". Worse yet, blood is full of proteins and other componds that denaturalize and coagulate rather quickly.

Comment: Actually, this is a perfectly sensible (from a zealous religion perspective) answer.  Emulating god is something many religions invite their adherents to do.  The fact that it's impractical is irrelevant (in fact, IMO, it enhances the answer).  +1

Answer (score 0):

You could make alcohol, like in this question. [Blood-based alcohol for vampires?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/149942/blood-based-alcohol-for-vampires) Depends on your taste though, blood isn't for everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce blood usage as a holy substance. People would use it for healing and to fight evil spirits consider it something akin to holy water in Catholicism.